# How to get file from resources when blank space is in path

Tags: java

I need parse `.yml` file with configuration.

File is located in `src/main/resources/configFile.yml`

Right now i have no problem until there is **no blank space** in some folder name in the path.

Example:

`E:\Tomcat-7.0\webapps\applicationName\WEB-INF\classes\configFile.yml` (OK)

`E:\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\applicationName\WEB-INF\classes\configFile.yml` (FAIL)

In second example i got `java.io.FileNotFoundException`.

I can not affect path. So i am looking for solution which will be able to handle it. Could you suggest how to proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should escape the space in the name, like:

```
"E:\Tomcat\ 7.0\webapps\applicationName\WEB-INF\classes\configFile.yml"
```

Or decode the path:

```
String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path);
```

Comment: This works for me...                
                decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path,"UTF-8");
                decodedPath = decodedPath.replaceAll("file:/", "");
                decodedPath = decodedPath.replaceAll("\\u0020", "\\ ");
                File verLocation = new File(decodedPath);